# How to loop through .txt files and search for a specific string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a few .txt log files and I am looking for a way to loop through all of them and look for a specific string inside. Once found all the results to be printed in a new .txt file. So far I've managed to create this:

```
import os
stringToMatch = 'dataToLookFor'
matchedLine = ''

with open('Logs/mylogs.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if stringToMatch in line:
        matchedLine = line
        continue

with open('Logs/results.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(matchedLine)
```

With this I am able to find results 1 by 1 but only in the file mylogs.txt. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: You are only opening `mylogs.txt`, where do you open the other files?

Comment: All the other files are in the same directory as mylogs.txt. I am just not sure how to create a loop which can go through all the files find the string I am looking for and either printed or add it in the results.txt file.

Comment: in that case, use os.listdir("Logs") to get a list of all the files in that directory. You might want to check if the file is a txt file if you have other files or folders in that directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at the `glob` [package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). With this package you can find all `*.txt` files and do the needful operations:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('Logs/*.txt')
```

will give you a list of files having `txt` file extension with in the `Logs` folder.

---

Having that, you can go through all the files and store matching lines to some output file:

```
string_to_match = 'dataToLookFor'

with open('Logs/results.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if string_to_match in line:
                    outfile.write(f'{f}: {line}')
```

Comment: I've added a break after the last line so the loop can stop. Everything else worked like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what it should look like but you can use os.listdir("Logs") to get all the files in that directory:

```
import os
stringToMatch = 'dataToLookFor'
matchedLine = ''

for file in os.listdir("Logs"):
    if ".txt" in file:
        with open('Logs/'+file, 'r') as file:
            for line in file:
                if stringToMatch in line:
                    matchedLine = line
                    continue

            with open('Logs/results.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(matchedLine)
```

Comment: I've just tried but still in my results.txt there is only one record. I saw that the script took around 4-5 seconds to finish so I guess it is looping through the files.